# Xcode 6/Swift Window Background

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift, osx-yosemite

I'm new to Xcode and Swift, and I'm trying to customize my App background, specifically the title bar (as for example the Spotify App does).

So I got it working on Mavericks, but since I installed the Yosemite Beta and the XCode 6 Beta 5, the changes are not applied although there's no code errors whatsoever.

The line I'm using is this:

```
 window.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 0.12, green: 0.12, blue: 0.12, alpha: 1)
```

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Seb

Comment: Did you ensure that window is still connected to whatever it is that  you wanted it to be connected to?

Comment: Maybe it's helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27042648/2360439

Answer (score 0):

I tried that on Yosemite and Xcode 6 and it did work form me:

```
 func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {

    window.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 0.12, green: 0.12, blue: 0.12, alpha: 1)

}
```