# NSWindowController in Swift. Subclassing and initializing with Nib

Tags: cocoa, swift, subclass, nib, nswindowcontroller

In a test Swift project, I am subclassing `NSWindowController`. My `NSWindowController` subclass is designed to work with a particular Nib file. It is desirable, then, that when my window controller is initialized, the nib file is automatically loaded by the window controller instance. In Objective-C, this was achieved by doing:

```
@implementation MyWindowController

- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:"MyWindowNib"]
    if (self) {
        // whatever
    }
    return self
}

@end
```

Now, in Swift this is not possible: `init()` cannot call `super.init(windowNibName:)`, because the later is declared not as a designated initializer, but as a convenience one by `NSWindowController`.

How can this be done in Swift? I don't see a strightforward way of doing it.

P.S.: I have seen other questions regarding this topic, but, as long as I've been able to understand, the solutions all point to initialize the Window Controller by calling `init(windowNibName:)`. Please note that this is not the desired beheaviour. The Window Controller should be initialized with `init()`, and it should be the Window Controller itself who "picks up" its Nib file and loads it.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the `init()` just to call `super.init(windowNibName:)`, you could instead just override the `windowNibName` variable.

```
override var windowNibName: String  {
    get {
        return "MyWindowNib"
    }
}
```

Then there should be no need to mess with the initializers.

Comment: In Swift 4, better like this: override var windowNibName: NSNib.Name?  {get { return NSNib.Name(rawValue: "MyWindowNib") }}

Comment: @Aarhus88 Doesn't work: Property 'windowNibName' with type 'NSNib.Name?' (aka 'Optional<NSString>') cannot override a property with type 'String?'

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own convenience initializer instead:

```
override convenience init() {
    self.init(windowNibName: "MyWindowNib")
}
```

You should instead opt in to replacing all designated initializers in your subclass, simply delegating to `super` where appropriate. Confer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24220904/1460929